# If $[F(a):F]=5$, find $[F(a^3):F]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

so as it is in the question.

Clearly $F(a^3)$ is a subfield of $F(a)$. So we know that $[F(a):F(a^3)][F(a^3):F]=5$ the problem now is, how do we know if $[F(a):F(a^3)]=5$ or $[F(a^3):F]=5$. The trouble is that $F(a^3)$ could possibly be $F(a)$ or $F$ depending on the multiplicative order of $a$. Or so I think, am I making a mistake somewhere? The question then goes on to ask if the argument applies if we change $a^3$ to $a^2$ or $a^4$. Any hints would be appriciated.

Comment: Hint: if $F(a^3)=F$, is it possible $[F(a):F]=5$?

Comment: @Wojowu ohhh because then the extension is of degree 3!

Comment: Or less, but at most 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, $$5 = [F(a):F] = [F(a):F(a^3)][F(a^3):F].$$ If the second term in the product is 1, then $a^3 \in F$, so that $[F(a):F] \le 3$. We know that's false! Hence the second value is 5, since it's not 1, and 5 is a prime.

Comment: So it works for $a^2$ and $a^4$ as well, same argument, right?

Comment: Yup! We just get different inequalities, but they're all impossible.

Comment: Thank you! I should have went step further and saw why thats impossible.

Comment: Your answer was very much helpful. Sorry to ask a silly question but I am a little confused why $[F(a):F(a^3)]\leq3$? Could you please explain this a bit?